# Determine if specific type of object exists in a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Is there an easy way to check if a specific type of object exists in a `tuple`?

There only way I can think is to iterate over the `tuple` and check every object, but knowing python I feel like there has to be a better way.

Comment: Since when a `for` loop is not a good way?

Comment: nope, being an ordered sequence there is no way other then going over each element.

Comment: @GLHF I was just curious if there was a more pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

At the root of the problem you do have to iterate over the list.  However, there are tools to make this easy, such as

```
if any(isinstance(x, <class>) for x in my_list):
```

At least this will short-circuit when you find the first one.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a better way than list comprehensions.

```
result = [x for x in mylist if type(x) is bool]
```

If anyone got a better solution I'm eager to see it.
But I'm betting my right sock on the fact that there's no other way than to involve a loop in any shape or form. In this case, a `for` loop.

---

Just because I got a nifty downvote without an explanation, here's a benchmark of the alternatives given thus far, and these are the median runtime results:

```
type() check: 0.837047815322876
isinstance() check: 0.84004807472229
any() check: 0.8540489673614502
```

Code is rather crude, but here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/d4297df9e0e64f4d5c3776a974355e5b) of the test.
I really don't see why this list comprehension thing would be bad, or wrong in any way.

1. It checks for a specific type (as requested)
2. You get a list of all the elements that is of that type
3. It's faster than the alternatives?

Again, the test is crude and maybe not perfect.
But hopefully I didn't mess up the useage of `any()` or any yield operators that I didn't think of.

Comment: For pete sake, what's the down votes for this evening?

Comment: it might have been for using `if type(x) is bool` instead of `if isinstance(x, bool)` but "specific type of object" makes me think that checking the exact specific type is fine for this case.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Might be why. And I can understand why `isinstance` should be used. But as you said, OP wanted to check the type and nothing else. Since `type()` is generaly faster than `isinstance()` I opted for fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if any(map(lambda x: isinstance(x, SomeClass), my_tuple)):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: it does work but note that any time you can use `map(lambda x: some_operation(x), thing)` it would be more clear to do `(some_operation(x) for x in thing)`

Answer (score 0):

```
type_you_are_checking_for in map(lambda x: type(x), your_objects_tuple)
```

examples:

```
>>> str in map(lambda x: type(x), (1, "sfds"))
True
>>> str in map(lambda x: type(x), (1, 2))
False
```